# Proving an inequality involving series

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, summation

Sorry for the vague question, didn't know how I'd word it.

I am trying to solve this and am looking for hints!:

> Choosing complex numbers $a_0,a_1, a_2, ... , a_n$ prove that there exists such $|\zeta = 1|$ (Also a complex number) so that $|\sum_{k=0}^n a_k \zeta^k| \geq \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n |a_k|^2}$ holds. Hint: You may use integration.

My ideas: Squaring the inequality and using $|z|^2 = z z^*$ and writing down first few terms of the resulting series on the left side of the inequality results in something like $\sum_{k=0}^n |a_k|^2 + mixed\ terms$ reducing the problem to proving that those remaining terms are greater or equal than 0. This is where I get stuck, I especially have no idea where I would use integration in proving this.

I'm not so good at proving: I've also thought of using induction to try and ease the problem, however I'm not sure if I can use induction here, since $\zeta$ may be different for each n so I couldn't make a simple n -> n+1 jump(Would be appreciated if someone could comment that too).

Could someone push me in the right direction?

Comment: added relevant tags to your question to get view from people in the know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(z):=\sum_{k=0}^na_kz^k$. Then using Parseval's Identity we get
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n|a_k|^2=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(e^{it})|^2dt\leq\sup_{t\in[0,2\pi]}|f(e^{it})|^2=|f(e^{is})|^2
\end{align*}
for some $s\in[0,2\pi]$, since $t\mapsto|f(e^{it})|^2$ is continuous. Thus, putting $\zeta=e^{is}$, we have that $|\zeta|=1$ and
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n|a_k|^2}\leq|f(\zeta)|,
\end{align}
as desired.